# HoloLens - Is there a possibility to combine MRTK and HoloLens2ForCV?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

I am starting a project where I need the following two things:

1. raw sensor data from the HoloLens 2 to create a point cloud
2. functionality and ui from [MRTK](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity)

The thing is that I'm using MRTK in a Unity project and the programming language is C#.
To get the depth information from the sensor I need to use the research mode, which is given by using [HoloLens2ForCV](https://github.com/microsoft/HoloLens2ForCV) and is written in C++.
I am currently still researching and trying to understand what direction I will take. What I have found so far is the following [plugin for Unity](https://github.com/petergu684/HoloLens2-ResearchMode-Unity), which is based on HoloLens2ForCV. Regardless of that, I would like to know what other possibilities there are and if anyone has already tried the same.

My Setup:

- Unity 2020.3
- MRTK 2.7.3
- latest state of HoloLens2ForCV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been working with HololensforCV (the 1st version) with MRTK for over half a year now. I have reused and edited multiple UI prefabs from MRTK. I have had no problem so far. The second version should not have any problems as well.

But I had issues with Unity 2020.3 versions. more info about the issue can be found here [OculusXRSDKDeviceManagerProfile](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/10015)

Hence my preferred Unity version would be Unity 2019.4.

Comment: But how do you combine them? As far as I know you implement in unity in c#, but after you build your project you get some "for me unreadable c++ project". So do you use the referenced [plugin](https://github.com/petergu684/HoloLens2-ResearchMode-Unity) from above or how do you do that?

Comment: Import the MRTK package like how you do normally. Then copy the dlls and .winmd from the HololensforCV C++ project into your unity plugins folder. The plugin you provided also uses similar steps. I do not get the issue you mentioned. I can suggest you have a look at the Issues page of the repos. There is much infos there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) right now I dont have an issue. I'm gonna try what you said.

Comment: Here is an example repo which i used to refer  [HololensforCV-Unity](https://github.com/doughtmw/HoloLensForCV-Unity)